# Dovecot Setup Normal and Shared mailboxes from 2 different LDAP queries

Tags: ldap, dovecot

Using a Postfix - Dovecot - LDAP Combo, I want to configure my Dovecot that it uses one query for "normal" inboxes for users and another query for shared mailboxes.

My goal is that I have users e.g. "john.doe@example.net" with an inbox and a shared imap folder "Shared/" that contains shared folders every user has access to.

The users come from one LDAP query (e.g. having a special field or a special class) and another query should define what shared folders exist (the shared folders would also have an own email address, e.g. press@, stage@, team@ etc.)

I know how I configure the normal mailboxes, but how can I setup the shared folders from a different query?

Is there any easy way to also setup access control to some of those shared folders from LDAP, e.g. that the user only has access of the user and the shared folder are in the same group or share an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

From the Dovecot Wiki, [Multiple Authentication Databases](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/multiple_authentication_databases/):

> Dovecot supports defining multiple authentication databases, so that if the password doesn't match in the first database, it checks the next one. This can be useful if you want to easily support having both local system users in /etc/passwd and virtual users.

With other words, simply define multiple passdb/userdb combinations. Preferably order them in number of incoming mails/connections, as the first of them is always queried.

Directly using LDAP to determine ACL groups is not possible in Dovecot, but is generally possible by using a [post-login script](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/PostLoginScripting) to [fetch the groups from LDAP](http://www.lunch.org.uk/wiki/sogodovecotldapandgroups).

Comment: how do I decide what of those ldap query is my normal users, and what are shared mailboxes?

Comment: I don't really get your question. If you want to be able to determine them inside the post-login script, user DB fields are passed through as environment variables. Is that what you're looking for?